# How do I fix this axios GET request? Keep getting 404 status code

Tags: python, reactjs, axios

Trying to get json data to front end and have tried a bunch of versions of axios requests but keep getting 404 status code.

This is an example of the front end format:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick () {
    axios.get('./hello')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ message: response.data.text });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="button-container">
        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
        <p>{this.state.message}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and back end routing:

```
@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
   return jsonify(text='hello world')
```

Error message says 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' or says http://localhost:5003/hello doesn't exist

Comment: You can access the link that you mentioned? localhost

Answer (score 0):

1. First check your server, which url and port, your api is exposed
2. You need to pass complete url to `axios` constructor otherwise it will send request to same origin/url where your client is hosted, .e.g webapp at `localhost:3000`.

So your code will be

```
const SERVER_URL = 'http:localhost:5000'
axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/hello`)
```

Comment: what;s your api url?